# How setup gunicorn to read custom settings with systemd

Tags: django, gunicorn

I migrated a server I had to Ubuntu 16.04 and `systemd` replaced `upstart`. I have three developing environments: Production, Staging and Development. Only the latter one uses a local database, the other two use a remote one.
So, in order to handle the deployment and the service I managed to create the following `systemd` service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn service for Project
After=network.target

[Service]
User=projuser
WorkingDirectory=/home/projuser/sites/Project/source
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=v3.settings_staging
ExecStart=/home/projuser/sites/Project/env/bin/gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:8090 --workers 6 --access-logfile ../access.log --error-logfile ../error.log v3.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The service starts, but it seems to ignore this line: `ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=v3.settings_staging`. I can see in the logs the following:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Mostly because it is using my default `settings.py` file, which I use for development.

How can I make sure it loads the staging settings.py file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, passing as an argument to `gunicorn` also works:

`--env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.settings`

https://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/run.html#gunicorn-django

What I wanted could be achieved by having the following file in `/etc/systemd/system`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn service for a Django Project
After=network.target

[Service]
User=a_user
WorkingDirectory=/home/a_user/project/source
Environment="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app.settings_staging"
ExecStart=/home/a_user/envs/project_env/bin/gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:8090 --workers 6 --access-logfile ../access.log --error-logfile ../error.log v3.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Note the following line: `Environment="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app.settings_staging"`.

https://www.linux.com/learn/understanding-and-using-systemd